# Seeing Web & Mobile Analytics data on DEs

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, analytics, web

Is it possible to get some simple data from a webpage and putting it on a DE via Web&Mobile Analytics? Something like "How many people visit the page today" or "Which pages have been clicked most?" Otherwise, should I use Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only manualy. For each Tile in Web & Mobile analytics you can drill down to selected audience and export it to data extension by clicking in orange arrow icon. This will create a data extension in Web & Mobile Analtics folder, but it will only contain data for identified visitors. Documentation avalible [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_anb_export_data_from_wama.htm&type=5)

[image]